# Error. BufferedWriter repeating lines at end of file

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I have here an error and dont know what is happening.

My class gets a vector of hashmaps and a rute, and then write that hashmap to a file in that route.

This is the code:

```
/* Variables de entrada */
    Vector vecHm = (Vector) context.getAttribute(sVecHashmap);
    String strFileLocation = "" + context.getAttribute(sFileLocation);


    // Inicializamos variables
    FileWriter fileWriter = null;
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;

    try
    {
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(strFileLocation,true);
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        String linea = "";
        String lineaCabecera = "";


        for (int i=0;i<vecHm.size();i++)
        {
            HashMap hm = (LinkedHashMap) vecHm.get(i);
            Iterator it = hm.entrySet().iterator(); 
            linea = "";
            while (it.hasNext()) 
            {
                Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                if (i==0)
                {
                    if (lineaCabecera.equals("") == false)
                    {
                        lineaCabecera = lineaCabecera + ";";
                    }
                    lineaCabecera = lineaCabecera + (String)pairs.getKey();
                }
                if (linea.equals("") == false)
                {
                    linea = linea + ";";
                }
                linea = linea + (String)pairs.getValue();
                //it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
            }

            System.out.println("PRF:: HashmapToFile:: Iteracion: " + i + ". Linea: " + linea);

            if (i==0)
            {
                System.out.println("PRF:: Pinto Cabecera. ");
                bufferedWriter.write(lineaCabecera);
                bufferedWriter.newLine();
                //bufferedWriter.write('\n');
            }
            bufferedWriter.write(linea);
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
            //bufferedWriter.write('\n');
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new WFException(" ERROR writing the file");
    } finally
    {
        try
        {
            // Cerramos el fichero
            bufferedWriter.close();
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new WFException(" ERROR closing the file");
        }
    }
```

I have a trace that show me the line to write in the file:

**System.out.println("PRF:: HashmapToFile:: Iteracion: " + i + ". Linea: " + linea);**

The log that i see is this (i will put only the last four iterations):

PRF:: HashmapToFile:: Iteracion: 90. Linea: eufekeptuil;null;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo

PRF:: HashmapToFile:: Iteracion: 91. Linea: hwukbzakmfuutrhnfzm;null;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo

PRF:: HashmapToFile:: Iteracion: 92. Linea: Securitas Europe;29-JAN-15;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo

PRF:: HashmapToFile:: Iteracion: 93. Linea: Tarifa New 544;05-FEB-15;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo

But... when i see the file... i have this at the end:

Securitas Europe;29-JAN-15;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo **-OK. Perfect-**

Tarifa New 544;05-FEB-15;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo **-OK. Perfect-**

And then:

N-15;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo **(repeated and unfinished line)**

Tarifa New 60;15-JAN-15;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo **(repeated line)**

vjvrqgxavk;null;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo;Inactivo **(repeated line)**

And another 15 more lines repeated.

Any clue?

Thanks all

Comment: (All the lines repeated not appear in the log twice, only once, when the proccess need to paint them in the suitable position). The first repetition appears in the file in line 40, the second in 41, third in 42... and then another time.

Comment: Why use raw types in 2015? Why not use try-with-resources in 2015?

Comment: Well, you could at least avoid using raw types; also, use a List instead of a vector etc

Answer (score 1):

Forget the problem. The files are good. The problem is in the downloader. The system is putting more data in that functionality.